# change fopen to stream

Tags: c++, file

I have the these code:

```
FILE *fp;
_wfopen_s(&fp, m_file, L"rb")
```

and

```
FILE *wmp
_wfopen_s(&wmp, s_file, L"wb")
```

I want to know how can I change above code to `ofstream` or `ifstream`, I know I can do something like this "`outfile.open("junk.dat", ios::binary | ios::out);`" with `ofstream`, But how I can put "`s_file`" and "`&wmp`" in `ofstream`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you want to continue using wide characters you should be using `std::wofstream` and `std::wifstream`.

Secondly, you don't use a `FILE*` at all, so no `&wmp` anywhere. The object you define is the file which you use to read from or write to. So you can have something like

```
std::wofstream wmp(s_file, wios::out | wios::binary);
if (wmp)
{
    // Here you have an open output stream, write wide characters to it
    wmp << L"Hello world\n";  // Writes a string to the file

    // Write some binary data to the file
    wmp.write(reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(some_data),
              size_of_some_data_in_bytes / sizeof(wchar_t));
    // The division is needed, as `write` write in units of `wchar_t`, not bytes
    // This is problematic if some of the data you want to write isn't an even
    // multiple of `sizeof(wchar_t)`

    // And so on...

    // Finally when done, close the file
    wmp.close();
}
```

Note that if you are not writing strings to the file, but only raw binary data then I suggest you use plain `std::ofstream` instead, as you won't have to think in units of `wchar_t` and can just think in units of "bytes".

If you want to learn more [this is an excellent reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) about the C++ I/O classes.

Comment: Thank you Joachim Pileborg, Also I used fwrite, fread in my code, What about them? for ex: fwrite(buf, RW, len, wmp); in my code, I should change it to wmp << buf << RW << len<< wmp ?!

Comment: @PaulJason The C++ stream equivalent of `fwrite` is the [stream `write` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write). Using the `<<` should only be used for text output (i.e. it converts integers to their textual representations and writes that).